# how to update an object in Hibernate Criteria without knowing it's id

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

I have this query that I would like to translate in Criteria Hibernate:

```
UPDATE Patient SET HourOut = ? WHERE IDQueue = ? AND TicketNumber = ? AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE(LastVisitDate), '%Y-%m-%d') = ?;
```

I understand the way to update an object when it's id is known but I can't figure out how to do it with the kind of *where* i have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples).

```
Patient example = new Patient();
example.setLastVisitDate(date);
example.setIDQueue(idq);
example.setTicketNumber(tnbr);

matchesDate = session.createCriteria(Patient.class)
                 .add(Example.create(example)).list();
for(Patient patient : matchesDate){
    Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
    patient.setHourOut(outH);
    session.saveOrUpdate(patient);
    t.commit();
}
```

Comment: i'll try it right away but meanwhile, i'd just like to know in terms of generated sql in background, how is it different than if i'd do first a SELECT on the object based on lastVisitDate/idQueue/ticketNumber and then the update on the returned Patient?

Comment: I dont understand. Do you mean the difference between static sql-strings and dynamic generated sql?

Comment: I mean I could also do it like that:
List<Patient> lp = session.createCriteria(Patient.class)
  .add(Restrictions.eq("ticketNb", ticketNb)
  .add(Restrictions.eq("idQueue", idQ)
  ...
Then loop on the returned list and process it as we do with the Example (setHourOut + update).

Would it be less efficient?

Comment: `Example.create()` does nothing else than `Restrictions.eq("ticketNb", ticketNb) .add(Restrictions.eq("idQueue", idQ) ...` but using example its more easy to read and understand.